# Understanding the buffering argument of the io.open() method in Python 2.7

Tags: python, io, buffer

I am trying to understand the the buffering argument of the [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) method in Python 2.7.

I execute in the Python interpreter:

```
import utils
buffer_size = 4000
file = open('test.txt','w', buffer_size)
file.write('\n'.join(map(str, range(10000))))
```

then I look at the `test.txt` file to see how many lines got written, even though I haven't called `file.close()` yet, and didn't do any manual `file.flush()` myself.

If `buffer_size = 4000`, I see that 9822 lines got written. However, `buffer_size = 8192`, I see that 8414 lines got written.

I get this behavior in both Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (Python 2.7.10 x64) and Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 (Python 2.7.10 x64). I don't understand where these numbers (9822 and 8414) come from.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Quote from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open): "any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes).". I.e: the buffer size is not guaranteed to be what you pass as parameter. It's impossible to predict how much of the buffer is in use and how much has been written to disk as your write overflow the buffer in both case and it's (the buffer) size is machine dependent.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks, interesting! I guess that answers my question :) You are welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, writing an actual answer would need to dive into python code to give factual information on how the buffer is built (I suspect there's a function of the memory page size, etc.) and that would be too long for an answer. (Hence my feeling of too broad here, I don't vote because of meta effect, I'd never seen this Q without the post on meta). Maybe a python expert will wish to complete it with factual information now it's back on top of active questions for the tag.

Comment: @Tensibai I think your could post your comment as an answer, without any modification. I agree one could dig further but the information should be sufficient for many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) (emphasis is mine):

> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer
>   size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, **any other positive**
>   **value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes)**. A
>   negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually
>   line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If
>   omitted, the system default is used. [2]

I.e: the buffer size is not guaranteed to be what you pass as parameter. It's impossible to predict how much of the buffer is in use and how much has been written to disk as your write overflow the buffer in both case and the buffer size is machine dependent.

As you didn't call an explicit flush, part of the buffer has been flushed and another part is still waiting for it to fill before flushing to disk.