# When is a write to disk triggered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, cpython, disk-io

In Python, I can open a file with `f= open(<filename>,<permissions>)`. This returns an object `f` which I can write to using `f.write(<some data>)`.

If, at this point, I access the original final (eg with `cat` from a terminal), it appears empty: Python stored the data I wrote to the object `f` and not the actual on-disk file. If I then call `f.close()`, the data in `f` is persisted to the on-disk file (and I can access it from other programs).

I assume data is buffered to improve latency. However, what happens if the buffered data grows a lot? Will Python initiate a write? If so, details on the internals (what influences the buffer size? is the disk I/O handled within Python or by another program/thread? is there a chance Python will just hang during the write?) would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that your question is at least partially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712445/what-is-the-use-of-buffering-in-pythons-built-in-open-function also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869247/understanding-the-buffering-argument-of-the-io-open-method-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general subject of I/O buffering has been treated many times (including in questions linked from the comments).  But to answer your specific questions:

- By default, when writing to a terminal (“the screen”), a newline causes the text to be flushed up through it.  For all files, the buffer is flushed each time it fills.  (Large *single* writes might flush any existing buffer contents and then bypass it.)
- The buffer has a fixed size and is allocated before any data is written; Python 3 doesn’t use `stdio`, so it chooses its own buffer sizes.  (A few kB is typical.)
- The “disk I/O” (really kernel I/O, which is distinguishable only in certain special circumstances like network/power failure) happens *within* whatever Python write triggers the flush.
- Yes, it can hang, if the file is a pipe to a busy process, a socket over a slow network, a special device, or even a regular file mounted from a remote machine.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what exactly you mean by "bypass" (when writing _Large single writes might flush any existing buffer contents and then bypass it._) ?

Comment: @Aimery: If the buffer is half-full and a request comes in to write a _byte array_ (the only thing supported natively by the OS) that is 3 buffers long, it’s better to flush the half-buffer and then OS-write the array than to copy pieces into the buffer (and make one extra system call).